# mySQL update using a where clause throws Primary Key error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I've searched the internet, the documentation, and extensively on stackoverflow, but to no avail.
I am using MySQL Workbench to try to concat some additional values on the end of a particular column.
My original code was:

```
update mySchema.myTable
set myColumn = CONCAT( myColumn , 
', "a108": "Additional Data.",
"a109": "More Additional Data. "'
)
where primaryKeyColumn =
(
select primaryKeyColumn
from mySchema.myTable
where column3 = "testdata" AND column4 = aNumber
);
```

However, this threw an error "Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'translation' for update in FROM clause".  I searched around on stackoverflow and changed my code to:

```
update mySchema.myTable
set myColumn = CONCAT( myColumn , 
', "a108": "Additional Data.",
"a109": "More Additional Data. "'
)
where primaryKeyColumn in
(
select primaryKeyColumn from
(
select primaryKeyColumn
from mySchema.myTable
where column3 = "testdata" AND column4 = aNumber
) as tempTable
);
```

This is now throwing "Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect."

I have checked, and the primaryKeyColumn is definitely the primary key.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I don't know if this is the only answer, but I was able to get it working by doing this:

```
SET @myPrimaryKey = (select primaryKeyColumn from mySchema.myTable where column3 = "testdata" AND column4 = aNumber);
update mySchema.myTable
set myColumn = CONCAT( myColumn , 
', "a108": "Additional Data.",
"a109": "More Additional Data. "'
)
where primaryKeyColumn = @myPrimaryKey;
```

That did it.

Comment: ... only for the special case where we are returning a single primaryKeyColumn value.  In the more general case, where  query could be returning more than one value, we can use a join to an inline view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not understanding why the table needs to be referenced twice.

Why wouldn't we just refer to the rows to be updated directly using the conditions on column3 and column4, e.g.

```
UPDATE mySchema.myTable t
   SET t.myColumn = CONCAT( t.myColumn , '...')
 WHERE t.column3 = 'testdata'
   AND t.column4 = aNumber
```

(I'm also not clear what `aNumber` is... if that's a reference to a column in the table, best pattern is to qualify it.)

---

In the more general case, where we have a subquery that gets the identifiers for rows that need to be updated, we can often make use of an inline view, and do a JOIN operation in the UPDATE

```
UPDATE mySchema.myTable t
  JOIN ( SELECT q.primaryKeyColumn
           FROM mySchema.myTable q
          WHERE q.column3 = 'testdata'
            AND q.column4 = aNumber
       ) s
    ON s.primaryKeyColumn = t.primaryKeyColumn   
   SET t.myColumn = CONCAT( t.myColumn , '...')
```

I strongly recommend writing that as a SELECT statement first, and reviewing the results, before we run an UPDATE.

```
SELECT s.primaryKeyColumn
     , CONCAT( t.myColumn , '...') AS newval_myColumn
     , t.myColumn                  AS oldval_myColumn
  FROM mySchema.myTable t
  JOIN ( SELECT q.primaryKeyColumn
           FROM mySchema.myTable q
          WHERE q.column3 = 'testdata'
            AND q.column4 = aNumber
       ) s
    ON s.primaryKeyColumn = t.primaryKeyColumn
```